# Magento : add new field system.xml for existing admin module, label is not translated

Tags: magento, module, label, translation, admin

I have an existing module in admin and have added a new field in system.xml for this module. The label will not be translated but the field is added. In fact only the name of the field is displayed in stead of translated text.

What is the problem (cache cleared) ?

This is the xml:

```
   <fields>
    <active translate="label">
     <label>Enabled</label>
     <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
     <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
     <sort_order>10</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </active>

    ... many fields ...

    <MODULE_SH_TNT_RATES_DISCOUNT>
     <label>MODULE_SH_TNT_RATES_DISCOUNT_1</label>
     <comment>MODULE_SH_TNT_RATES_DISCOUNT_2</comment>
     <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
     <sort_order>690</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                           
    </MODULE_SH_TNT_RATES_DISCOUNT>
```

It is an own written admin shipping module, running for years, but I added one new field for a customer. I have language .csv files where this label is translated as all other labels for fields. When I change existing labels for existing fields, they will be replaced, but new labels for new fields seem not to be translated. So in my case only MODULE_SH_TNT_RATES_DISCOUNT_1 and MODULE_SH_TNT_RATES_DISCOUNT_2 are showen without translation from the .csv files.

Comment: can you share added xml part which you have added into system.xml

Comment: Rajiv thanks for your reaction, I have added the xml to the question

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at a core module's system.xml

```
<!-- ... -->
<catalog translate="label" module="catalog">
    <class>separator-top</class>
    <label>Catalog</label>
    <!-- ... -->
```

See the `translate="label"`?  That's what tells Magento the `<label/>` node needs translation.

See the `module="catalog"`?   That tells Magento which module's helper object to use for translation.

```
$translated_string = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Catalog');
```

You XML looks like its missing those nodes.  I'd start there.

Comment: Hi Alan, I updated the xml above. That's my structure working for years, will be translated in different languages. But I added last field (to an existing module), field is added and can be used in program's, but the label is not translated, it seems a bug for me ..

Comment: Maybe you mean I have to specify <MODULE_SH_TNT_RATES_DISCOUNT translate="label"> but I did not for the many fields, and still they are translated .. I shall try and let you know ..

Comment: This is just stupid, translate="label" is not necessary, but I made a write error in the .csv files, I just forgot "_TNT_" in the label field name, I did not see it (sometimes blind) ... sorry for this unneeded question ..